# Question regarding notation of a language decidability

Tags: turing-machines, computability, church-turing-thesis

$1.\: A_{DFA} = \{\langle B, w \rangle \mid B \text{ is a } DFA \text{ that accepts input string } w \}$
$2.\:A_{DFA} = \{\langle B \rangle \mid B \text{ is a } DFA \text{ that accepts input string } w \}$

I know how to proof that **1** is decidable by constructing a machine that always halts and accepts whenever $B$ accepts, otherwise rejects. what's the difference between **1** and **2**. I find that it doesn't make sense to not include $w$ inside the encoding brackets but I have seen this notation in other places. are they both the same?

Answer (score 2):

The languages are not the same.

---

In the first one, $w$ is a part of the input.

In the second one, $w$ is fixed beforehand, and the language has to depend on what you fix it to be.

Comment: Will that affect the proof that $A_{DFA}$  is decidable. by other means, How is it possible to proof that a language is decidable if $w$ is not part of the input?

Comment: It definitely can only help if $w$ is fixed beforehand and is not a part of the input, but in any case both languages are decidable since we can emulate the DFA until it halts (and it always halts)